# Returning a random element from my custom ArrayList class?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have made my own generic version of the ArrayList class and it needs to include a method that returns a random element from the list. Here is the method I wrote:

```
public T randomElement() throws NoSuchElementException {
    T elem;
    int rand = (int) (1 + Math.random() * size);
    elem = items[rand];

    return elem;
}
```

I am using this class/method to pick a random element from my list (using characters taken from a .txt file) and I keep getting a NullPointerException error. Are there any protocols I can take to make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: On which line are you getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: is `items` initialized?

Comment: What is the NPE you're getting?  If you're talking about getting NPEs in the invoking code because this method sometimes returns `null`, then you can compactify your backing array whenever you remove an element, like `java.util.ArrayList` does.

Comment: Yes, there is one protocol: ensure that `items != null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is the way you compute the random index `rand`:

```
int rand = (int) (1 + Math.random() * size);
```

Because of the `1 +` the value might be equal to `size` which is the index of the first empy space in your list (at least I assume that).
So in some cases you return the value of an index that has not been set yet - which is `null`.
Change it to

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * size);
```

Comment: wouldn't/shouldn't  that cause a NoSuchElementException rather than NullPointerException?

Comment: Why would it? There is no check in the method whatsoever. It may cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds though if `items` is full. The question should clarify where the NPE occurs....

Comment: Sorry, yes its backed by an array, so to my mind i would expect ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)  Assuming the array is the same size as the list of course.  I have never looked at how ArrayList is implemented though.

Comment: And the `1 +` is useless anyway because index 0 is a valid index.

Comment: In an ArrayList the backing array can be larger than the current size of the list. You just keep a pointer to the next free index :)

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException could be happening because of one of two things -

1. items is null. Check the condition and return null.
2. Caller is not handling a returned null.

In any case, calculation of random index is wrong. Assume size of ArrayList is 5 and Math.random returns 0.9. In this case,

```
rand = (int)(1 + 0.9 * 5) = 5
```

This is the size of the ArrayList and will result in an out-of-bounds access. Just remove the "1+"